# Is there are any similar algorithm to Hungarian method but for solving matrix with size n*m?

Tags: algorithm, hungarian-algorithm

Is there are any similar algorithm to Hungarian method but for solving matrix with size n*m?

(n - workers, m - tasks, m > n, every worker must has at least 1 task)

The variant with adding dummy worker is incorrect, because in this case, at least 1 task will be without a worker.

Example:

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | T1 | T2 | T3 | T4 |
| W1 | 2 | 9 | 6 | 3 |
| W2 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 |
| W3 | 5 | 5 | 7 | 2 |

And the result is:

W1 - T2

W2 - T4

W3 - T1, T3

Comment: I don't understand your remark about dummy workers. Can't you make m - n dummy workers that can do each task as cheaply as the cheapest worker?

Answer (score 2):

If you want every task to be assigned to a worker even if that means more than one task is assigned to each worker then run the algorithm once using a dummy row

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | T1 | T2 | T3 | T4 |
| W1 | 2 | 9 | 6 | 3 |
| W2 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 |
| W3 | 5 | 5 | 7 | 2 |
| D1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

This will assign W1 to T1, W2 to T2, W3 to T4, and D1 to T3. Since T3 was assigned to a dummy worker it was essentially not assigned. If you remove all of the tasks that were assigned to a worker and add dummy columns you can run it again with

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | D1 | D2 | T3 |
| W1 | 0 | 0 | 6 |
| W2 | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| W3 | 0 | 0 | 7 |

Which will assign T3 to W2. So the final assignments are:
W1 to T1
W2 to T2 and T3
W3 to T4

Comment: Thanks, I will try to run algorithm as you say, and I forgot to mention that my task is for maximization.